# GAE - Facebook graph porting

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

Does anyone know any places where I may be able to find a `python` (AppEngine) port for the `Facebook Graph` `object` code?

The example [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/) shows the sample code:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http://';
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>

<html>
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['fb:app_id']);?>">
      <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo strip_tags(curPageURL());?>">
      <meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:type']);?>">
      <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:title']);?>">
      <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:image']);?>">
      <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:description']);?>">
      <title>Product Name</title>
  </head>
    <body>
      <?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['body']);?>
    </body>
</html>
```

but of course since this is PHP, I need to find an equivalent for Python to use in Google's App Engine.

**Has anyone seen anything like this in Python?**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the framework you are using but this should be trivial.

With Django templatetag, `get`:

```
@register.filter(name='get')
def get(o, index):
    try:
        return o[index]
    except:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
```

In Django, given that you have the request in the context:

```
<html>
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{ request.GET|get:"og:type" }}">
    <meta property="og:url" content="{{ request.get_full_path }}">
    ... 
    <title>Product Name</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ request.body }} <!-- {{ request.raw_post_data }} if Django < 1.4 -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Using webapp request, you do not have the `GET` attr like the `Django` request obj, you would need to use [the various properties of the webapp request class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass).